# amCharts wrong Zoom startDates and endDates

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using amCharts for displaying stock data. I have 7 zoom levels: `1H, 1D, 1W, 1M, 3M, 1Y, MAX`. For 1H, 1D, I am using a dataset which contains minute wise data. For 1W, 1M, I use a different dataset which has hour wise data. And for rest 3 levels, I have another dataset with day wise data. Now here is my problem:

When initially, I load minute wise data at default zoom level 1D, and add a listener `"changed"` to `chart.periodSelector`, after clicking on 1W button or any further zoom level button, the difference in minutes between startDate and endDate of generated event: `var minsDiff = (event.endDate.getTime() - event.startDate.getTime()) / 60000` is always equal to number of minutes in **1 day** (1440) instead of **7 days**.

I suppose this may be because the current dataset loaded is minutes dataset with 1440 max number of datapoints. So it may be setting date range for 1 Week equal to that of 1 Day because only that much data is available. But what I want is actual date range of 1 week if I click 1W button because I want to load a different chart with different dataset (hour wise data for 1W).

I tried using listener `"zoomed"` of chart. But same problem persisted.

Comment: Can you post your chart config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally out of scope periods are not visible unless you set [`hideOutOfScopePeriods`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PeriodSelector#hideOutOfScopePeriods) to false. As you noticed, if a period is greater than the amount of data available then the chart will truncate the zoom to fit the data you have.  Checking the `predifinedPeriod` property in the [`changed`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PeriodSelector#changed) event is a surefire way to see which button was clicked, which will help in this scenario where the data doesn't necessarily encompass the entire period:

```
listeners: [
  {
    event: "changed",
    method: function(eventObj) {
      console.log("clicked " + eventObj.predefinedPeriod);
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you please also look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023787/amcharts-chartscrollbar-going-out-of-chartdiv as no one out there seems to know anything about it and only you can help for that question. Thanks again.