# AmCharts: ChartScrollBar going out of chartdiv

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts

I am Using amCharts for displaying stock data. I have a scrollBar enabled and positioned at bottom. I have a chartholderdiv which has style:

```
#chartholderdiv{
  height:80%;
  width:80%;
  overflow:visible;
  background-color:#db946b;
}
```

For clarity, I have added a background color to see the limits of div in the following image.
I have a chartdiv (which is provided to AmCharts.makeChart) which has style:

```
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chartholderdiv">
    <div id="chartdiv"></div>   
</div>
```

There are no other style or tags in my file for which I have pasted output. If the browser is resized to smaller size, the issue will be clear. I have given all my code here except the `<script>` tag which has amCharts config and `AmCharts.makeChart(chartdiv,chartobject);`(this command is called within ajax onreadystatechange function). So more or less my script tage is:

```
<script>
 chartObject={......};

 var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     .....//parse json data for dataset of chart.
     .....//set chartObject dataProvider to dataset parsed above
     chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", chartObject);
   }
  };
  xhttpHour.open("GET", dataUrlString, true);
  xhttpHour.send();

</script>
```

But when the chart is drawn, the scrollbar of chart goes out of the chartdiv/chartholderdiv. See image:

[image]

I have added the red background so that the problem is visible. I assume that when setting height, the two graphs take 70 and 30 as in chart config and the scrollbar is added after that which spills out of div but I want the chartholder div to resize to accommodate everything. I have tried many things, but the problem persists.

Comment: I couldn't replicate this issue just by using your styles. This is likely happening due to other CSS classes. Could you add the whole structure that is wrapping the chart?

Comment: There is nothing except what I pasted in this question before. But still I have added the javascript that I have(not whole because its too much of code in script tag and not useful for this question). Thanks for looking into this. Eagerly waiting for a solution.

Comment: The issue will be more clear with smaller browser window size. I noticed it when viewing the page in mobile and same for small window size of desktop.